# Cannot load rJava because cannot load a shared library

Tags: java, r, path

I have been struggling to load the rJava package in R.

I get the following messages

```
> library(rJava)
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared library \
     'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-210~1.1/library/rJava/libs/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.


Error : .onLoad failed in 'loadNamespace' for 'rJava'
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'rJava'
```

I have tried so many solutions that they are all bamboozeled in my head. 
At some point I even got

```
> R Console: Rgui.exe - System Error The
> program can't start because
> MSVCR71.dll is is missing from your
> computer. Try reinstalling the program
> to fix this problem.
```

I made sure everything I could think of was on the path

```
> C:\Program Files\R\Rtools\bin;C:\Program Files\R\Rtools\perl\bin;
  C:\Program Files\R\Rtools\MinGW\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;
  %SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
  %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
  C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;
  C:\Program Files\R\R-2.10.1\library\rJava\libs\;
  C:\Program Files\R;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client
```

What should I try next?

I am running R version 2.10.1 (2009-12-14) and I have also tried R version 2.10.1 Patched (2010-03-03 r51210). It is on a Windows machine running windows 7 enterprise

Comment: Do you have a Java Run-Time Environment (JRE) or even a Java SDK on your system?

Comment: At some stage (but relatively early) I went to http://www.java.com/en/ and downloaded java from there. I went back to that website now and used their Java test and received the following iformation: Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. Version: Java 6 Update 18 Operating System: Windows 7 6.1 Architecture: x86.  The program seem to be sitting in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6. I do not really know how paths work. Does one have to specify down to the actual subdirectory or can I just point in the general vicinity and the software will know to look in the subdirectories. Thanks for reformatting my post.

Comment: Proper installation of a given the 'component' usually takes care of adjusting the PATH e.g. that is what R does.   The rJava text I quoted talks about getting Java info from the registry, so I presume something is borked on your box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on some of Dirk's sage advice:

- Your path should probably say `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\` (remove "client").
- Your path should also have `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.10.1\bin\`.  You don't need that explicit reference to the rJava libs.  I would also then remove `C:\Program Files\R` from the path.
- Lastly, confirm that Java is accessible by either going to your command prompt and typing `java -version`, or from within R by typing `system("java -version")`.
- If you install the SDK, then you will also want a system variable `JAVA_HOME` which in my case points to `C:\Sun\SDK\`.

Comment: I am busy going through your suggestions. I will give you feedback when I get to see if it works or not.

Answer (score 14):

If you have read this threat and neither of the suggestions above has worked so far, then it might be worth trying one further:

- Windows 7
- R version 2.12.1 (2010-12-16) 64-bit
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

  `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\`

  `Path= ...;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\;C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12.1\bin\x64\`

The thing that finally solved my problem was to explicitly add `\server\` to the PATH variable.

Comment: Same here, ` \server\` was needed. The way I found out was by running `library("rJava")` from R GUI, which printed jvm.dll is missing. Emacs prints entirely different error message. After I added ` \server\` to path, both emacs/ess and gui versions worked ok.

Comment: I can concur. Thank you for putting this answer here.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, putting `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\[server]` in my `PATH`  worked for me. It seems the rJava module could jot find `jvm.dll` there.

Here are the versions of R and Java that I'm using (on 64-bit Windows 7).

Java:

```
java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode)
```

R:

```
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 5):

System information:
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

I encountered this same problem.  I was able to solve the issue with one line of code into the command window obtained from this [website](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/).

> Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\Program Files\Java\jre7')

Note that I used this particular line because I was on a 64 bit system. See website for 32-bit example.

Answer (score 3):

After editing your post for readability / formatting it seems that you have no Java system in your path. I don't use the OS you're trying to use this on, but on mine `rJava` only works if I also install a Java Run-Time Environment or, better still, a Java SDK.

Note that the package clearly lists

```
SystemRequirements: java
```

and that the [**rJava site**](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/) clearly states the following

> **Installation**
>
> First, make sure you have
>   JDK 1.4 or higher installed (some
>   platforms require hgher version see R
>   Wiki). On unix systems make sure that
>   R was configured with Java support. If
>   not, you can re-configure R by using R
>   CMD javareconf (you may have to
>   prepend sudo or run it as root
>   depending on your installation - see
>   R-ext manual A.2.2 for details). On
>   Windows Java is detected at run-time
>   from the registry.
>
> rJava can be installed as any other R
>   package from CRAN using
>   install.packages('rJava'). See the
>   files section in the left menu for
>   development versions.
>
> JRI is only compiled if supported,
>   i.e. if R was configured as a
>   framework or with --enable-R-shlib.

so I think we have a few smoking guns pointing the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and had to do an additional fix: Setting the R path explicitly to ...bin\x64, and also being consistent in using x64 Java and R.