# Error while reading xlsx file in R

Tags: r, xlsx

I am getting the following error :

> Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object 'E:/anwesha/applications/R-3.5.0/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found

while performing the following code:

```
dat <- xlsx::read.xlsx(file = "getdata%2Fdata%2FDATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, rowIndex = 18:23, colIndex = 7:15)
```

Can anyone plz help me in re
solving the error by explaining which library or module is missing here. I do already have `xlsx` package

## R datareading

Comment: You need to set your JAVA_HOME variable. Try this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399027/cannot-load-rjava-because-cannot-load-a-shared-library

Comment: In the mean time, you can use the `readxl` package. It doesn't depend on `rJava` as far as I know, but you can only read excel files and not write as you would be able to using the `xlsx` package.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me. Try to do following:

- Check the `JAVA` installation on your machine. Find which operating system are you using (32 bit or 64 bit); make sure you install the correct version of `JAVA`.
- It is also important to download correct R version; If you installed x64 `JAVA`, you need to install `x64` R on your machine.
- set your directory; go to system environment setting and add following:

  `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7")` # for 64-bit version `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7")` # for 32-bit version
- reinstall `rJava`

  `install.packages("rJava")`

  `library(rJava)`

  `library(xlsx)`

this will resolve your isssue.

For another way to quickly read/write `xlsx` worksheet in R, you can try `library(openxlsx)` which works well for the same purpose.

Comment: I also recommend `openxlsx::read.xlsx()`, it doesn't require Java. Note that it can only read xlsx files, not xls. For writing xlsx, I have the best experience is with 'writexl::write_xlsx()'

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to consider is the `read_excel` function from the `readxl` package:

```
read_excel(path, sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, na = "", skip = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Java that meets your systems Operating System i.e 32 or 64 bit and ensure it is compatible with your version of R.

After that move the downloaded file to documents under libraries.